# Incorrect index value and original index value for content moderator API?

Tags: azure-ai

On sending `Is this a crap email abcdef@abcd.com, phone: 6657789887, IP: 255.255.255.255, 1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052` to `Content Moderator` API - https://uksouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/contentmoderator/moderate/v1.0/ProcessText/Screen?classify=false, the `json` response correctly identifies the harmful word - `crap`

```
"Terms": [{
    "Index": 3,
    "OriginalIndex": 10,
    "ListId": 0,
    "Term": "crap"
  }],
```

Why is the `index value 3` and `original index 10`? If I count the words or letters in the original text, it doesn't match